# CodeIgniter Model Not Found

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I am trying to connect mysql with CodeIgniter. I got this error:

```
load->database(); 
$query = $this->db->get('student'); return $query->result(); } } ?>

Fatal error: Class 'Student_model' not found in 
C:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter\system\core\Loader.php on line 303
```

Here is my code:

**MODEL**

```
class Student_model extends CI_Model
{

    function __Construct()

    {
        parent::__Construct();
    }

    public function student_getall()
    {
        $this->load->database();
        $query = $this->db->get('student');
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

**VIEW**

```
foreach($query as $row)
{
    print $row->fname;
    print $row->lname;
    print $row->roll;
    print $row->address;
    print "<br>";
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
class Student extends CI_Controller
{
    function __Construct()
    {
        parent::__Construct();
    }

    public function getall()
    {
        $this->load->model('student_model');
        $data['query'] = $this->student_model->student_getall();
        $this->load->view('student_view',$data);
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure your model file name is lower case

Answer (score 2):

the problem is

```
function __Construct()
{
        parent::__Construct();
}
```

you can see the capital `C` instead of `c`.

Once more thing, make sure that you started with file using `<?php` and ending file with `?>` without any space after `?>`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to load the database library automatically, since it will be used frequently. You can define it in application/config/autload.php file and the variable is,

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

You file name of the model should be,

```
student_model.php
```

and the class name should be

```
Student_model

and $this->load->model('student_model') = $this->load->model('Student_model');
```

this is not case sensitive.

`

Answer (score 0):

```
May be your model starts with <?
And in yuour php.ini, shorttages is off thats why the issue is there.
Either enable shorttag or user <?php instead of <?
I found out this solution.
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
function __Construct()
{
    parent::__Construct();
}
```

should be small 'c' s. Please check if you have correctly saved `student_model.php` in your models folder in

> /Codeigniter/application.models